# .antMatchers().permitAll() parece não funcionar

Tags: spring, spring-security

`Edit02`

Habilitei `spring-security` em meu projeto, e agora todas as API precisa de autenticação, perfeito era isso que eu precisava.

Porem quero que apenas uma API não precise de autenticação. Tentei utilizar 
`.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/informacoes/**")
            .permitAll()`

mas isso não funciona e continuo recebendo:

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Pesquisando achei muitos artigos, e a grande maioria sugerem desta forma:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions

https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html

Estou com o seguinte codigo:

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;



@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http, WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Chamou HttpSecurity");

          http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/informacoes/*")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

API

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")

@RequestMapping(value = "/informacoes/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object[]> informacoesUsuario(@Valid @PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {

        Object[] response = usuarioServices.informacoesUsuario(id);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    }
```

SecurityCORSFilter

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Chamou SecurityCORSFilter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, Content-Type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mfac</groupId>
    <artifactId>mfac</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mfac</name>
    <description>mfac - rest</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Segurança | Início -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Segurança | Fim -->




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

O interessante é que se eu fizer um Request, para qualquer API, o console não imprimi `Chamou HttpSecurity` parece que as configurações de `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` não estão sendo aplicadas.

Saída do console, apos um Request:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa desabilitar a CSRF antes de autorizar as requisições, tente desta forma:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/informacoes/*")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    ;
}
```

---

Inclui nos comentários um [gist](https://gist.github.com/ngueno/dc0406d42dbef42255f495a1afbb6581) contendo uma configuração funcional do  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Como o configurer nem é chamado, acredito que na verdade seja um problema na configuração do `@EnableResourceServer`

---

Conforme mencionei nos comentários, para configurar o CORS adequadamente você não precisa de um filtro, a classe `CorsConfigurationSource` fará o trabalho, conforme descrito na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html):

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return configSource;
}
```

Lembre-se de habilitar também na configuração de autorização:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/informacoes/*")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    ;
}
```

---

Não esqueci de você meu amigo, só não tive tempo de fazer seu exemplo mesmo :)

Abaixo coloquei um exemplo com comentários da configuração do Authorization e Resource Server:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    // Id da aplicação, este ID deve ser utilizado no Resource Server, isso indica que o Authorization Server está emitindo um token para ser utilizar por este Resource
    private static final String APPLICATION_RESOURCE_ID = "my-application-id";

    // Token store compartilhado entre o Authorization Server e o Resource Server
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            // Configuração em memória de usuários para teste
            clients.inMemory()
                        .withClient("nullptr")
                        .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("secret"))
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(APPLICATION_RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        // Configurações de token store e Resource Id
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(APPLICATION_RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        // Configurações de autorização para a controladora
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/simple").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/simple").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
        }
    }

}
```

Inclui esta controladora simples para executarmos os testes:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/simple")
public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "Hi there :)";
    }
}
```

**Vamos então para as chamadas:**

Na configuração do servidor eu configurei o client `nullptr` com senha `secret`, então faremos a autenticação para pegarmos o token através do Authorization Server (realizei através do Postman):

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic bnVsbHB0cjpzZWNyZXQ=
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2de597db-640f-46b2-acbd-4e5293ffe4c3,fc03c3f6-f2ce-4c15-bbbc-750102f9801d
Host: localhost:8080
cookie: JSESSIONID=2325944BF8FC184676D2C56F43193BD4
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 29
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Com este POST, obtive o token de autorização conforme o esperado:

```
{
    "access_token": "6ffdf3e5-cf71-4426-911f-5655cddcf679",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

Agora que já obtive o token farei a requisição para a controladora, passando o token de autorização no header:

```
GET /simple HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer 6ffdf3e5-cf71-4426-911f-5655cddcf679
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f1bbcf6b-5c97-41e8-bac2-e1cb2bcb89e7,451b27ce-2ff3-4659-b675-357b405581ad
Host: localhost:8080
cookie: JSESSIONID=2325944BF8FC184676D2C56F43193BD4
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

E pronto, temos a resposta:

```
Hi there :)
```

Temos os casos em que enviamos a requisição sem token, e temos o retorno:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

E quando enviamos com token inválido:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid access token: meutokenerrado"
}
```

Com isso você já consegue ter uma base de configuração do OAuth2, você pode então desabilitar o controle de usuários `inMemory()` e utilizar `jdbc()`, e configurar mais detalhes de como buscar os usuários com um `ClientDetailService` customizado.

Note que não configurei CORS em momento algum, caso necessário configuração e liberação de CORS deve-se utilizar as configurações que já passei anteriormente.

Você pode encontrar mais material abaixo:

[Spring Security OAuth Site](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)
[Aplicações de exemplo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2)

Comment: Atualizei o código, mesmo assim não funciona. Coloquei 2 console log (Atualizei a pergunta) e parece que o WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Não esta sendo chamado

Comment: Acredito que seja devido às configurações de Authorization e Resource Server, você de fato precisa delas neste momento? Você irá manter o authorization e resource juntos?

Comment: Criei um [gist](https://gist.github.com/ngueno/dc0406d42dbef42255f495a1afbb6581) de um projeto meu que está funcionando

Comment: Desculpe não entendi, você esta se referindo ao ``SecurityCORSFilter`` ? Se sim, tive que colocar pois estava me retornando erros de Cors, por conta do OPTIONS que o navegador manda, unica solução que encontrei, foi colocando os ``SecurityCORSFilter``

Comment: Estou verificando o gist, muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: As annotations `@EnableAuthorizationServer` `@EnableResourceServer` `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` só as deixe se de fato irá prover todas as configurações de resource e authorization server

Comment: Retirei as annotations `@EnableAuthorizationServer` `@EnableAuthorizationServer ``@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`, porem agora ele nao reconhece a API para pegar o token, se eu fizer um request para `/oauth/token` ele me retornar `timestamp:"25/06/2019"
status:404
error:"Not Found"
message:"No message available"
path:"/oauth/token"` Como retirei as annotations, preciso fazer a API para pegar o Token manualmente ?

Comment: @Dup, então você está utilizando a infra do authorization server, como você estava passando o token para o servidor depois da autorização?

Comment: ai que está, depois que retirei as anotações a API de onde eu pegava o token aparentemente nao existe mais, agora estou tentando criar um ``tokenServices`` para ser chamado na minha API ``oauth/token`` mas estou com duvidas se é realmente isso que precisa ser feito.

Comment: Não precisa, a annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer` que habilita isso. Porém você deve configurar como você valida o token novamente, ao habilitar o `@EnableResourceServer` o server deve validar o token através de alguma configuração, você configurou a validação de token?

Comment: Não fiz nenhuma configuração, todas as configurações do projeto esta na pergunta, não tenho nada a mais que isso. Você teria Discord ? consigo mostrar mais detalhes do projeto por la, se quiser me adicionar Dup
#1537

Comment: Irei disponibilizar um exemplo funcional também utilizando configurações de authorization e resource server

Comment: Ok muito obrigado

Comment: Reparei que se remover a anotação ``@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`` da classe ``SecurityCORSFilter`` o ``WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`` é chamado e impresso no console  ``Chamou HttpSecurity``, mas por usa vez, isso faz com que eu tenha problemas com CORS OPTIONS em Request de domínios diferentes, pois a classe ``SecurityCORSFilter`` não é mais chamada, após a remoção da anotação. Teria alguma forma de fazer com que as duas Classes tenham efeito na aplicação ? pois preciso de ambas, uma para problemas de CORS e outra para liberar acesso a uma API sem precisar de autenticação.

Comment: @Dup na realidade você não precisa de um filtro para implementar as configurações de CORS, você deve utilizar a classe [CorsConfigurationSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html). Adicionei também um exemplo na resposta

Comment: Adicionei o ``@Bean CorsConfigurationSource`` no ``WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`` porem continua me retornando erro ``OPTIONS http://192.168.25.26:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=password&username=1&password=1 401`` para resolver esse problema, no meu antigo ``SecurityCORSFilter`` eu tinha o seguinte codigo ``if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }`` para quando tiver um Request do tipo ``OPTIONS`` retornasse com o ``Status 200 OK``.  Agora como posso ter o mesmo resultado usando CorsConfigur.. ?

Comment: Altere a property `config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));` e tente novamente, a configuração é assim mesmo para funcionar o CORS, parece mágico :)

Comment: Alterei, continua o mesmo erro, o interessante é que as Request que faço não esta imprimindo ``"Chamou HttpSecurity"`` no console, tenho a impressão que essas configurações não estão sendo usadas.

Comment: Você teria algum exemplo, onde funcionasse a questão de ``OPTIONS CORS`` e as configurações de``WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`` esteja funcionando, pois acredito que estou perdido com essas annotations, de quais usar e se preciso configurar elas separadas.

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver esse problema, nao encontrei nenhum artigo que mostre como posso configurar corretamente as classes do Spring.

Comment: @Dup, adicionei mais detalhes para você

Comment: @Dup conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Estou tentando ainda, convertendo o seu exemplo pro meu caso de uso, acredito que vá da certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http//
                .cors().and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and()//
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()//
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/informacoes/**").permitAll()//
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```